# Combining results into one if multiple

Tags: codeigniter

I have these two functions below

```
public function get_posts() {
    $this->db->select('p.post_id, p.reply_id, p.user_id, u.username');
    $this->db->from('post as p');
    $this->db->join('user as u', 'u.user_id = p.user_id');
    $this->db->where('p.post_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
    $this->db->or_where('p.reply_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
    // $this->db->group_by('p.user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Results Output

```
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_id` = '1' AND `reply_id` = '0' AND `user_id` = '2'
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_id` = '3' AND `reply_id` = '1' AND `user_id` = '1'
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `post_id` = '5' AND `reply_id` = '1' AND `user_id` = '1'
```

Total Posts Function

```
public function total_posts_by_user($user_id, $reply_id, $post_id) {
    $this->db->from('post');
    $this->db->where('post_id', $post_id);
    $this->db->where('reply_id', $reply_id);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    // $this->db->group_by('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
```

The total_posts_by user gets the number of post shown in image below

[image]

> **Question** As you can see there are 2 admin row results showing. But I
>   would like them to be combined so it will just say row for admin and 2
>   posts.

I have tried using group_by() on get_post but dos not work

Controller

```
<?php

class Who_replied extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['posts'] = array();

        $results = $this->get_posts();

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['posts'][] = array(
                'username' => $result['username'],
                'total' => $this->total_posts_by_user($result['user_id'], $result['reply_id'], $result['post_id'])
            );

            $this->total_posts_by_user($result['user_id'], $result['reply_id'], $result['post_id']);
            echo $this->db->last_query() . '</br>';
        }

        $data['total_posts'] = $this->total_posts();

        return $this->load->view('default/template/forum/categories/who_replied_view', $data);

    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `group_by('p.post_id')` only in first method `get_posts()`? moreover you may try by `DISTINCT` post_id

Comment: @RejoanulAlam Just did still same.

Comment: please check my answer

Comment: I did same thing bit strange.

Comment: echo the query (`echo $this->db->last_query()`  in first method) & then run this in your DB, check how many rows are returned. 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

Use `left` join in first method because current it is using inner join. After that use group by

```
public function get_posts() {
    $this->db->select('p.post_id, p.reply_id, p.user_id, u.username');
    $this->db->from('post as p');
    $this->db->join('user as u', 'u.user_id = p.user_id','left');
    $this->db->where('p.post_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
    $this->db->or_where('p.reply_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
    $this->db->group_by('p.post_id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

and try. If still face same issue double check whether there are same TWO username `admin`

** Have you tried `DISCTINCT`?
hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

I have found my solution from [here](http://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-66259-post-337050.html#pid337050) using COUNT(p.user_id) AS total

```
public function get_posts() {
$this->db->select('p.post_id, p.reply_id, p.user_id, u.username COUNT(p.user_id) AS total');
$this->db->from('post as p');
$this->db->join('user as u', 'u.user_id = p.user_id');
$this->db->where('p.post_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
$this->db->or_where('p.reply_id', $this->input->get('post_id'));
$this->db->group_by('p.user_id');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
}
```